# Logger conflicts with my own logger

Tags: ros, rospy, ros-kinetic, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I call `rospy.init_node`, logging of errors using my own defined logger stops working and nothing is displayed. For example when I call an object without its arguments, I get a `TypeError` printed on the interpreter but after I call `rospy.init_node` the same object instantiation without arguments goes through without any error being printed. This then makes it difficult to debug my code.

The logger I use is derived from the Python `logging` module. I am using Python3 with the Python2 `rospy` module in the Ubuntu terminal multiplexer `screen`. I am using ROS Kinetic.

My question is: Does anyone know how to resolve such a problem? Can I use the `rospy` logger with my own?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292615/logger-conflicts-with-my-own-logger/) by [jaduol391](https://answers.ros.org/users/35546/jaduol391/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Same issue for me.

I have a completely working python logger, but when I wrap my python code in a ROS node, python logging is disabled.

As I have seen, this is a known issue: for unknown reasons, normal python logging is disabled after a call to rospy.init_node(). So far, the only solution seems to be to redirect the logging message in the ROS logging.

Maybe, this could be useful: [Override Logging Configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging#overriding_node_log_file)

---

Originally posted by [antop](https://answers.ros.org/users/31282/antop/) with karma: 36 on 2018-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2